# Bash brace expansion not working on Dockerfile RUN command

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile, brace-expansion

I'm running the following RUN command in my Dockerfile, expecting a "logs" directory to be created under each of the listed subdirectories:

```
RUN mkdir -p /opt/seagull/{diameter-env,h248-env,http-env,msrp-env,octcap-env,radius-env,sip-env,synchro-env,xcap-env}/logs
```

But when I check the image, I see a directory literally called "{diameter-env,h248-env,http-env,msrp-env,octcap-env,radius-env,sip-env,synchro-env,xcap-env}" created under /opt/seagull, instead of brace expansion taking place.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know one way or the other, but does `RUN` run under bash?

Comment: It turns out, it depends on whether you're using the shell form or the exec form. See my answer below.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You're not using brace expansion, because you're not using Bash. If you look at the [documentation for the RUN command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/run):

> RUN  (shell form, the command is run in a shell, which by default is /bin/sh -c on Linux or cmd /S /C on Windows)

And also:

> Note: To use a different shell, other than ‘/bin/sh’, use the exec form passing in the desired shell. For example, RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "echo hello"]

So, just change the command to use the exec form and explicitly use a Bash shell:

```
RUN [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "mkdir -p /opt/seagull/{diameter-env,h248-env,http-env,msrp-env,octcap-env,radius-env,sip-env,synchro-env,xcap-env}/logs" ]
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I spent 45 minutes on this, trying different escaping techniques, checking default bash settings, etc.

Comment: Wait, what? You've answered you own question, and you're thanking yourself for it...?

Comment: Yes! :) It's been an exhausting day, and I needed to thank myself for finally RTFM. Also, http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: It's not the answering own question that confused the hell out of me, it was just the comment, but hey, if it's deserved ;D

Comment: Could you not `ln -f /bin/bash /bin/sh`, I believe the reason is that typically nowadays `/bin/sh` is a symlink to `/bin/dash`.

Comment: Important note from the official documentation:  _The exec form is parsed as a JSON array, which means that you must use double-quotes (“) around words not single-quotes (‘)._

Answer (score 12):

If `/bin/bash` is available in your image, you can change the shell that the docker build system uses to execute your `RUN` command, like this:

```
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
```

Now, your `RUN` command should work unchanged.

Comment: So worth the scroll past the accepted answer.