# How to copy multiple files in one layer using a Docker file to different locations?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-copy

Is it possible to copy multiple files to different locations in a `Dockerfile`?

I'm looking to go from:

```
COPY outputs/output/build/.tools /root/.tools
COPY outputs/output/build/configuration /root/configuration
COPY outputs/output/build/database/postgres /root/database/postgres
```

I have tried the following, but no joy:

```
COPY ["outputs/output/build/.tools /root/.tools","outputs/output/build/configuration /root/configuration","outputs/output/build/database/postgres /root/database/postgres"]
```

Not sure if this is even possible.

Comment: If `COPY outputs/output/build/ /root/` or something along those lines doesn't do what you want, then no.

Comment: I think you'll have to copy them all to a single destination and then `mv` them each manually.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy multiple files in one layer using a Dockerfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30256386/how-to-copy-multiple-files-in-one-layer-using-a-dockerfile)

Comment: @user719662 no, it's not a duplicate of that question. That question pertains to copying multiple files to one location. This is about copying multiple files to multiple locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a file `.dockerignore` in your `docker` build context directory. Create a soft link (`ln`) of the root directory you want to copy and exclude the directories you don't want in your `.dockerignore`.

In your case, you don't need the soft link as the directory is already in the `docker` build context. Now, add the directories in the `.dockerignore` file that you don't want eg. if you don't want `bin` directory you can do that as,

```
# this is .dockerignore file
outputs/output/build/bin*
```

Finally in your `Dockerfile`,

```
COPY outputs/output/build/ /root/
```

Details are [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file).

Answer (score -2):

it looks like you are trying to do bash style `[]` brace expansion
`RUN` command uses `sh` NOT `bash`

see this SO article discussing it

[Bash brace expansion not working on Dockerfile RUN command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40164660/bash-brace-expansion-not-working-on-dockerfile-run-command)

or the docker reference

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/run

Comment: I'm not sure you understood the question. The question was *"Is it possible to copy multiple files to different locations in a Dockerfile?"* not "Why isn't this command working?". The OP tried the command with [ ] to no avail to accomplish the original problem.